# Lumia 920 Release Date

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I haven't heard anything on the release date of the Nokia Lumia 920.

I am an avid iPhone user, but I am planning to switch.

Does anyone know an exact or estimated release date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Canada, the Lumia 920 was supposedly released today (November 12) by Rogers](http://mobilesyrup.com/2012/11/12/rogers-releases-the-nokia-lumia-920/). Rogers will have exclusivity for at least a month. Nokia is only making the black color available in Canada.

It may take a while for them to be distributed to the various Rogers stores across Canada. But they have them [for order at the Rogers site](http://www.rogers.com/web/link/wirelessBuyFlow?forwardTo=PhoneThenPlan&productType=normal&productId_Detailed=LUM920BLK&N=52%2011) for $99 with select 3-year plans or $550 without a plan.

If you go to your My Rogers account, you can [reserve a phone](http://www.rogers.com/web/Rogers.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=NEW_GCT&_nfls=true&setLanguage=en&template=Rogers-Reservation-System&cm_mmc=redirects-_-wireless-_-nrs-en-0912-_-rogersreservations), and you will be able to pick one up within 15 business days.

Answer (score 4):

For the USA, the 2nd of november will be the date for AT&T followed by all others in maximum 10 working days, at least thats what they are saying.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. I'm in Canada, we are usually a week behind for release dates.